# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in For loop

Tags: java, for-loop, concurrentmodification

I am trying to program an IM software,
I want to let user leave the conversation and tell his partner that he has left...
I prefer to use for loop instead Iterator, seek all the users and get the user who ask to leave and remove him... like that:

```
   for(Clientuser Cu: EIQserver.OnlineusersList)
          if(Cu.ID.equals(thsisUser.ID)) // find the user who ask to leave 
          {
          Omsg.setBody("@@!&$$$$@@@####$$$$"); //code means : clien! ur parter leaves...
                 sendMessage(Omsg); // sed message to thje partner with that code
                 EIQserver.OnlineusersList.remove(Cu);// remove the partner
                EIQserver.COUNTER--;// decrease counter.

          }
```

I get Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

I was using iterators, and to get rid of this exception, I convert to for, but the same exception still appears!!
how may I get rid of this exception?

Comment: You cannot remove something from a list which you are looping through.

Comment: @Trick unless you remove it using the same iterator you are using on the loop or you are using a collection that supports it, like CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Comment: You should definitely read this (not an answer): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: True. By the way @EsmaeelQash, try to follow Java Coding Standards (Naming Conventions). If you will ever pass your code, it create a pain for your follower :)

Comment: I'll edited the question to follow naming conventions...

Comment: No need to do that now :) Just have in mind for your future endeavors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) instead of looping. For example:

```
Iterator<Clientuser> iterator = EIQserver.OnlineusersList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Clientuser next = iterator.next();
    if(next.ID.equals(thsisUser.ID)) {
        Omsg.setBody("@@!&$$$$@@@####$$$$"); 
        sendMessage(Omsg); 
        iterator.remove();// remove the partner
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, kocko, but does iterator.remove() removes the object from the EIQserver.OnlineusersList??

Comment: Yes, it removes the last fetched object from list.

Answer (score 3):

Faulting line:
`EIQserver.OnlineusersList.remove(Cu);`

You can only remove elements from a collection that is being iterated over via the `Iterator` object you are using to iterate.

```
for (Iterator<Clientuser> it = EIQserver.OnlineusersList.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
{
    Clientuser cu = it.next();
    if (!cu.ID.equals(thsisUser.ID))
        continue;
    // other code
    it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Iterator` for do something with list in loop:

```
Iterator<Clientuser> iter = EIQserver.OnlineuserList.iterator();
for(;iter.hasNext();) {
    Clientuser Cu = iterator.next();
    if(Cu.ID.equals(thsisUser.ID)) {
        Omsg.setBody("@@!&$$$$@@@####$$$$"); 
        sendMessage(Omsg); 
        iterator.remove(next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is also to transform the Collection to HashMap, save id's to remove and then remove it from the HashMap.

```
Collection<Integer> removeIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Map<Integer,ClientUser> all = new HashMap<Integer,ClientUser>();

for(Clientuser Cu: EIQserver.OnlineusersList) {
all.put(cu.ID,Cu);
      if(Cu.ID.equals(thsisUser.ID)) // find the user who ask to leave 
      {
      Omsg.setBody("@@!&$$$$@@@####$$$$"); //code means : clien! ur parter leaves...
             sendMessage(Omsg); // sed message to thje partner with that code
            EIQserver.COUNTER--;// decrease counter.
    removeIds.add(Cu.ID);

      }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As you are Iterating the EIQserver collection class, you can not remove element from the same class. Use a different collection for Iteration and remove the element from EIQserver class.

```
 List temp = ListofEIQserverobject;
  for(Clientuser Cu: temp.OnlineusersList){
    ..... your code then 
      EIQserver.OnlineusersList.remove(Cu);
    }
```

Comment: To do that temp should be a copy of the list, not a reference to itself.